# How will I be able to download the entire website with its codes and database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am currently developing a website which it can create an examination and generate the exam result using php and html canvas. I am now puzzled on what my next step will be. I really need a sample website that can be my basis in making my own. How will I download the entire website code and the database?

Comment: do you have server details ?

Answer (score 1):

to get the database out, you will need to export the content of database into a file. Look into `myslqdump` command, if you are using mysql.

To move whole website, you will need to ftp the root directory (probably compressing it first, maybe with tar) where all your css, javascript and HTML files are. Same applies to PHP scripts.

But to be a cool kid, you will need to store your files in some sort of Source Code Version Control system, such as GIT or SVN. Then its just a matter of checking out your branch on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not download server side code and database of any website until you are a genius hacker who can hack into the desired system and get access to all the things you need.

Breaking into any system is illegal and as per your country law you can be jailed or fined a huge amount.

If any can download my code then world don't need any more programmers and software developer as they could download some ones software and just modify it.
I would suggest you better start coding to complete your project or start hacking to steal it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - unless you have full access to the server.

I strongly advise to create yourself a github account and search for open source php apps, from which you can learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding after read your question, if you meant to download some online web and its database then it is not ethical but still there are some other ways to accomplish your need.

Here in [Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=examination%20php), there are lot of apps availble as you need

Also there are a lot of resources and frameworks available all you have to do is google your need

Comment: what is the use of GitHub ?